# def xxx(*args) where arguments may be any object. How to get sum of numbers in arguments?

Tags: python

I have a function with arbitrary number of arguments and need to add those arguments when they are numbers or can be turned to numbers.
Example:

```
def object_sum(*args):
    pass

print(object_sum(3, 'sun', '5', ['5', 'earth'], (5, '5')))
#Would print 23
```

Comment: Why isn't it `8`? You can't convert a list or tuple to a number.

Comment: @Barmar lol, are you a teacher ? Your question is pedagogically perfect for StackOverflow beginners !

Comment: Is `['5', 'earth']` not a number or do you want to iterate that sequence and get its numbers? How many levels of nesting? Is there a list in a list in a list?

Comment: Loop over the arguments. Try to convert it to a number. Use `try/except` to catch if it fails. If it's iterable, call the function recursively with that as the arguments.

Comment: @Programmer - Its an important question. Should sequences be iterated? Which sequences? It can end up infinite. A sequence that iterates iterable sequences forever.. `str` is that way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to catch the nested integers, do:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable


def object_sum(*args):
    def flatten(l):
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158532/4001592
        for el in l:
            if isinstance(el, Iterable) and not isinstance(el, (str, bytes)):
                yield from flatten(el)
            else:
                try:
                    yield int(el)
                except ValueError:
                    yield 0

    return sum(flatten(args))


print(object_sum(3, 'sun', '5', ['5', 'earth'], (5, '5')))
```

**Output**

```
23
```

Comment: I don't think this works correctly for multi-character strings, because `iter(i)` will iterate over the digits.

Comment: you need to try `int(i)` first, then use `iter(i)` in the `except`

Comment: @Barmar Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Test if the argument is a list or similar, if yes, recurse into it, if not, try to convert it to an integer:

```py
def object_sum(*args):
    result = 0
    for arg in args:
        arg_type = type(arg)
        if arg_type in (list, tuple, set, range):
            result += object_sum(*arg) # The asterisk is important - without it, the recursively called function would again call itself, and we'd get a RecursionError
        else:
            try:
                result += int(arg) # Try to convert to int
            except ValueError:
                pass # arg is not convertable, skip it
    return result

print(object_sum(3, 'sun', '5', ['5', 'earth'], (5, '5')))
```

Output:

```py
23
```